# Как сделать красивый вид ссылок?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как сделать красивый вид ссылок по типу:
https://site.ru/user?id=1 или https://site.ru/user?id=test
в
https://site.ru/1  или  https://site.ru/test

Имеется файл .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

а так же файл index.php:

```
// Определяю page из ссылки...
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
$Page = 'index';
$Module = 'index';
} else {
$URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
$Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
$Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);


if (!empty($Module)) {
$Param = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
$Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
}
}
}

// Подключаю страницы в зависимости от page следующим способом...
if($Page=='index')include('page/index.php');
elseif(!$Page)include('page/index.php');
elseif($Page=='user')include('page/profile/user.php');
...
```

Читал похожие статьи на эту тему, но не нашел решения для этого вопроса..

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,QSA,L]` передавайте в реврайте весь путь в параметр. А в индексе его берите из `_GET` вместо `$_SERVER`

Comment: возможно я не совсем верно сформировал вопрос.. как переделать вид ссылок из https://site.ru/user?id=1 --->  https://site.ru/1  ?

 если возможно, то рассмотрите, пожалуйста, это:
https://site.ru/user?id=1 --->  https://site.ru/user/1

Comment: Разобрать изначальную ссылку с помощью `parse_url`. Разобрать строку запроса с помощью `parse_str`. Из полученных данных пересобрать окончательную ссылку используя банальную конкатенацию с проверками.